# Org mode export: exclude sections with todo keyword

Tags: org-mode, org-export, todo

I want to export an org mode document so that sections or subsections
with `TODO` keywords do not appear in the exported output. How can
this be achieved?

The [export-settings](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html)
documentation does not explicitly mention anything related to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an export option to control exporting of TODO items:

> tasks: Toggle inclusion of tasks (TODO items), can be nil to remove
>   all tasks, todo to remove DONE tasks, or a list of keywords to keep
>   (org-export-with-tasks).

Setting it to `nil` will hide tasks from your exported document.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want to export `DONE` items but not `TODO` items, set it (`tasks`) to `done`.

Answer (score 0):

I used `tasks:nil`. For example, I use this in a sub-tree where I want to exclude tasks from export:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_OPTIONS: tasks:nil
:END:
```