# Org Mode export options: do not export TODO keyword sections

Tags: org-mode, org-export, tags

I read in the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html#Export-Settings), and [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/org-mode-export-exclude-sections-with-todo-keyword) that

```
#+STARTUP: overview
#+TASKS: nil

* TODO Config tasks                                                :tasklist:
** TODO todo1
   SCHEDULED: <2020-02-16 Sun>
** TODO todo2
   SCHEDULED: <2020-02-17 Mon>
   :LOGBOOK:
   - State "TODO"       from              [2020-02-13 Thu 01:26]
   - State "TODO"       from              [2020-02-13 Thu 01:26]
   :END:
```

**#+tasks: nil** should stop the exporting of todo items. It doesn't using the md backend. What am I doing wrong?

My org export config is as follows:-

```
** Self documenting config file
   #+begin_src emacs-lisp

    (use-package ox-gfm
      :defer 3 
      :after org
      :config 
      (defun config-export-to-markdown()
        (interactive)
        (if (and (eq major-mode 'org-mode) (file-exists-p (concat (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name)) ".md")))
            (org-gfm-export-to-markdown)))

      (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'config-export-to-markdown))

   #+end_src
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct option to exclude task keywords is the following:

```
#+OPTIONS: todo:nil
```

See all export options here: https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html

Comment: Many thanks. I had mistakenly opted for tasks:nil. I didn't rtfm properly.

Comment: Also, mind that there are no spaces in the sequence `todo:nil`. Otherwise, you get an ugly error traceback.